# Buying a domain name after its expire date

Tags: domains

I want to register a new domain name  but it is already taken. When I visit that domain name it shows some ads by a hosting company. They're not using that domain name for any purpose.

whois domain info shows it is owned by a hosting company and it is expiring a few months from now. Can I buy that domain if I hurried soon after or on its expiration date? Will it be available on domain checkers at web hosting pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to buy the domain when it expires, unless someone beats you do it or the current owner renews it.

There are companies out there that specialise in buying up expired domains and using them for generating ad revenue (because an expired domain will still have incoming traffic from other sites). Some also re-sell them for a significant markup (especially if the domain had large amounts of traffic before expiring). This is a form of [domain parking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_parking).

Some domain registrars (like GoDaddy) offer the ability to backorder a domain, which involves paying up front for a chance at getting the domain immediately when it expires. Of course it still doesn't help if the current owner chooses to renew, and if multiple people backorder the same domain, it usually ends up on an auction.

Bottom line - just because a domain name is set to expire at a given date doesn't mean it'll actually be available for purchase at that time.

Comment: Oh I See!!! so is that means i can buy that domain on 2012-09-30 ?

Comment: @NaveenChamikaraGamage Like I said - unless the current owner renews the domain or someone buys it before you do, yes, you can *try* to buy it on 2012-09-30.

Comment: @NaveenChamikaraGamage Chances are it'll get renewed in August or so. Don't hold your breath.

Comment: As on Whois Domain info it was created on 2010-09-30 & at that time it should be set to expire on 2011-09-30 ! Right? but this domain owner(ad company) has renewed(updated) it on 2011-10-18 !! that means after 18 days of expiration ! if i treid to catch it this time???

Comment: @NaveenChamikaraGamage It's more likely that they bought it for 2 years from the beginning, so this is the first time it's expiring. And that update might refer to updating of contact information, name servers or anything else, it doesn't mean the domain was renewed at that date.

Comment: Oppz!!! thats on their hands... and i found an old article wrote on 2002,I dont know wether these steps are valid now on domain deletion.According to that Article -
1. The registrar keeps the name for about 1 to 45 days after it has
expired. It's in their discretion if they want to delete it sooner or
later, but within that period.
2. Once the registrar tells the registry they won't keep it anymore,
the registry will keep it in "redemption period" for 30 days in case
its last registered owner decides to get it back at the last minute.

Comment: 3. If the name isn't redeemed after 30 days, the registry will let the
name be in "pending delete" for 5 days. Ideally, it'll be available on
the 6th day at about 2PM EST.